# 2 LayoutDrawers on same side

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I cant find answer if there is solution for implementing 2 `DrawerLayouts` on same side (2 `LayoutDrawers` with `layout_gravity="start"`). I can open 2 drawers on sam side but when i try to close drawer second drawer i get error.

```
05-05 20:03:34.577: E/AndroidRuntime(14638): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 20:03:34.577: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):    at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.continueSettling(ViewDragHelper.java:719)
05-05 20:03:34.577: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.computeScroll(DrawerLayout.java:764)
...
```

i don't use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` i overrided `onOptionsItemSelected` to catch action bar icon clicks and open drawers with

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerFrameLeft);
```

Code is working ok when i have drawers on left and right side.

Comment: How would that even work from an UX perspective?

Comment: Well second drawer whould slide in from left and overlap first drawer

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `layout_gravity="start"` for multiple layout drawers, you must to consider where is left navigationand right navigation, and you must to use `layout_gravity="left"` for your left navigation and `layout_gravity="right"`for your right navigation, such as below :

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#123456"
         />
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is one of  [good](http://www.stayrocks.com/2014/04/creating-navigation-drawer-in-android.html) example for left and right navigation drawer, hope it helps.